# Updating multiple paths in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have two entities in my app - `User` and `Shift`. They share a Many-to-Many relationship.

This is how I structured my database, using the denormalization technique and 4 top nodes:

```
{
   "shift-assign":{
      "-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w":{
         "111":{
            "email":"john@gmail.com",
            "firstName":"John",
            "id":"111",
            "lastName":"Smith",
            "password":"111",
            "phone":"555",
            "wage":30.0
         },
         "222":{
            "email":"jane@gmail.com",
            "firstName":"Jane",
            "id":"222",
            "lastName":"Doe",
            "password":"222",
            "phone":"678",
            "wage":32.5
         }
      },
      "-Lwsj8yE6HW2IUoTVJ0G":{
         "111":{
            "email":"john@gmail.com",
            "firstName":"John",
            "id":"111",
            "lastName":"Smith",
            "password":"111",
            "phone":"555",
            "wage":30.0
         }
      }
   },
   "shifts":{
      "-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w":{
         "date":"20191224",
         "endTime":"12:00",
         "key":"-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w",
         "startTime":"10:00"
      },
      "-Lwsj8yE6HW2IUoTVJ0G":{
         "date":"20191224",
         "endTime":"14:00",
         "key":"-Lwsj8yE6HW2IUoTVJ0G",
         "startTime":"11:00"
      }
   },
   "user-assign":{
      "111":{
         "-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w":{
            "date":"20191224",
            "endTime":"12:00",
            "key":"-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w",
            "startTime":"10:00"
         },
         "-Lwsj8yE6HW2IUoTVJ0G":{
            "date":"20191224",
            "endTime":"14:00",
            "key":"-Lwsj8yE6HW2IUoTVJ0G",
            "startTime":"11:00"
         }
      },
      "222":{
         "-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w":{
            "date":"20191224",
            "endTime":"12:00",
            "key":"-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w",
            "startTime":"10:00"
         }
      }
   },
   "users":{
      "99999":{
         "email":"",
         "firstName":"Admin",
         "id":"99999",
         "lastName":"",
         "password":"111",
         "phone":"",
         "wage":0
      },
      "111":{
         "email":"john@gmail.com",
         "firstName":"John",
         "id":"111",
         "lastName":"Smith",
         "password":"111",
         "phone":"555",
         "wage":30.0
      },
      "222":{
         "email":"jane@gmail.com",
         "firstName":"Jane",
         "id":"222",
         "lastName":"Doe",
         "password":"222",
         "phone":"678",
         "wage":32.5
      }
   }
}
```

I'm able to insert, read and delete `User` , `Shift` objects but when it comes to updating them , things get a bit complicated.

If I want to update a user's wage for instance, I'd have to loop through all the shifts the user is assigned to (under `user-assign/$id`), store all of the shifts' keys and then reference `shift-assign/$shift-key` for every stored key and update the wage. 
This would require nested `EventListener` which I'm trying to avoid.

The same problem with updating `Shift` nodes obviously.

Is there a better approach for solving this?

Comment: If all shifts for a user are under `user-assign/111`, it requires a single listener to read them. It might help if you edit your question to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should really only reference the id's in your `user-assign` and `shift-assign` nodes instead of whole objects. Denormalization doesn't require you to create duplicate copies of a whole document. For example, to simplify your structure would result in:

```
{
   "shift-assign":{
      "-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w": ["111", "222"],
      "-Lwsj8yE6HW2IUoTVJ0G": ["111"]
   },
   "shifts":{
      "-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w":{
         "date":"20191224",
         "endTime":"12:00",
         "key":"-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w",
         "startTime":"10:00"
      },
      "-Lwsj8yE6HW2IUoTVJ0G":{
         "date":"20191224",
         "endTime":"14:00",
         "key":"-Lwsj8yE6HW2IUoTVJ0G",
         "startTime":"11:00"
      }
   },
   "user-assign":{
      "111":["-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w", "-Lwsj8yE6HW2IUoTVJ0G"],
      "222":["-Lwo52vuW9QqCmAfS90w"]
   },
   "users":{
      "99999":{
         "email":"",
         "firstName":"Admin",
         "id":"99999",
         "lastName":"",
         "password":"111",
         "phone":"",
         "wage":0
      },
      "111":{
         "email":"john@gmail.com",
         "firstName":"John",
         "id":"111",
         "lastName":"Smith",
         "password":"111",
         "phone":"555",
         "wage":30.0
      },
      "222":{
         "email":"jane@gmail.com",
         "firstName":"Jane",
         "id":"222",
         "lastName":"Doe",
         "password":"222",
         "phone":"678",
         "wage":32.5
      }
   }
}
```

Then, you can just perform client-side joins to retrieve their associated objects.

This has several advantages:

1. If you were to update a user's data, you wouldn't have to update every other occurrences of user in any nodes. Similarly, if you were to update a shift, you will only have to update it in one place.
2. Save up storage space - again, you don't have to create copies of same documents. You just need their id's and retrieve it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

use map as path(after refrance) and value and then use updateChildren method

as ex if you want to update multiple name of user

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
//key for path and value in map for value in node 
map.put("/users/" + userId1 + "/name/", "ahmad");
map.put("/users/" + userId2 + "/name/", "mahmoud");
map.put("/users/" + userId3 + "/name/", "martin");
map.put("/users/" + userId4 + "/name/", "nameValue");
//and so on
myRootRef.updateChildren(map);
```

and so on ,and you can use loop if you hava multiple data